# Solution of ODE strictly monotone increasing

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Let $f \in C^1(\mathbb R)$ and look at $y'(t) = f(y(t))$, $y(0) = y_0$ such that $f(y_0) > 0$. Show that every solution is strictly monotone increasing.

---

My idea:

It is clear, if $f>0$ on $\mathbb R$. So assume that $y'$ is not strictly increasing. So there exists $a$ with $y'(a)=f(y(a))\leq 0$. By intermediate value theorem there exists $\xi$ between $0$ and $a$ so that $y'(\xi)=f(y(\xi))=0$. Now I don't know how to got on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $\psi:I\to\mathbb R$, be a solution of the IVP
$$
y'=f(y), \quad y(t_0)=y_0, \qquad (\star)
$$
where $I$ interval, with $t_0\in I$. It suffices to show that
$$
f\big(\psi((t)\big)>0, \quad\text{for all $t\in I$}.
$$
Suppose that $f\big(\psi((t_1)\big)=0$, for some $t_1\in I$. If $y_1=\psi(t_1)$, then $f(y_1)=0$, and hence the constant function $\tilde \psi(t)\equiv y_1$, would be a solution of the IVP
$$
y'=f(y), \quad y(t_1)=y_1. \qquad (\star\star)
$$
But $\psi$ satisfies $(\star\star)$ as well, and due to uniqueness enjoyed by both IVPs (since $f$ is $C^1$), we have that $\psi=\tilde\psi$. Contradiction, since $\psi'(t_0)=f\big(\psi(t_0)\big)=f(y_0)>0$.

If $f\big(\psi((t_1)\big)<0$, for some $t_1\in I$, then due to Intermediate Value Theorem, there would be also a $t_2\in I$, where $f\big(\psi(t_1')\big)=0$, again leading to a contradiction.